# Data Type increment

Tags: python, types, increment

I want to find out something but I can't really find an answer on how to do this.

So for example there is a data type **'int'** in Python
and you declare a random variable `x = 1` such as this and you can increment it by doing this `x += 1` or `x = x + 1` which would evaluate to `x` being `2`

Is there a way to declare your own data type.. like if I would want to set `y = AA` and then I could increment it like `y += 1` which should mean that `y` is now `AB`

I know that I could use a list with all the values and increment it from there but is there a better way.

and the limitation of a list is that for example if my `y` is currently at `ZZ` and I increment it I would expect to get something like this `AAA` but I cannot possible put all the values in the list.

Comment: Objects that can be added in python have a 'magic' `__add__` method. You can write your own method into `__add__` which will do whatever you want: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__

Comment: You can create a class for that.

Comment: Sure, you can create your own object class that has this characteristic. You'll want to read up on the [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

Comment: Thanks guys I'll look into this :)